# Trouble with Networkx + Matplotlib Animations - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_visible'

Tags: matplotlib, animation, networkx

I've been having some trouble getting the following animation of DFS to run.
I believe it might be because there is no background canvas, but I'm not sure exactly how to fix this, as all other similar implementations online use plt.plot rather than nx.draw in saving images to be displayed.

Can someone offer any guidance?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import ArtistAnimation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
colors = [0]*len(g)
cmap = plt.get_cmap("autumn")

g = nx.random_tree(20)
pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(g, k=0.1)


ims = [[nx.draw_networkx(g, pos, node_color = colors, cmap = cmap, ax = ax, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)]]

artists = [(nx.draw_networkx(g, pos, node_color = colors, cmap = cmap, ax = ax, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0),)]

stack = [0] 

while stack:
    node = stack.pop()
    
    if colors[node]: 
        continue
        
    colors[node] = 0.8
    stack += list(g[node].keys())
    
    img = nx.draw_networkx(g, pos, node_color=colors, cmap=cmap, ax=ax, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
    ims += [img]
    
anim = ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, blit = True)
# plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `nx.draw_networkx()` doesn't return anything and it's always easier to use `FuncAnimation` method instead. At first, you need to create a color generator to make the animation function switch to the next color set by each call. Then using the `FuncAnimation` you can animate your frames (plots):

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.animation as animation

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
plt.ion()

g = nx.random_tree(20)
colors = [0] * len(g)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('autumn')
pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(g, k=0.1)

# here you make the generator
def change_colors():
    stack = [0]
    
    yield colors

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if colors[node]:
            continue

        colors[node] = 0.8
        stack += list(g[node].keys())

        yield colors

# instantiate your generator
color_gen = change_colors()


def update_frame(n):
    # clear the plot
    plt.cla()
    # here switch to the next colors
    colors = next(color_gen)
    # then draw
    nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True, node_color=colors, cmap=cmap, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), update_frame, repeat=False, interval=1000)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

which will give you:
[image]
you can save it as a gif file by replacing `plt.show()` with `ani.save('anim.gif', writer='imagemagick')`.

Comment: Thanks for your code! I can see that it works for you, but when trying ani.save('anim.gif', writer='imagemagick') I got  'str' object is not callable on the filename.

Comment: So the plot works and you only cannot save it as gif? if yes, can you tell me how are you trying to save it? with what name?

Comment: I am using google colab, so I commented the mat Tkagg, as well as the plt.ion and plt.ioff lines. All of the other code is identical to yours, and plt.show() is replaced by ani.save(filename = 'anim.gif', fps = 60).  This gives the following error: MovieWriter stderr:
[gif @ 000001da8bbca380] GIF muxer supports only a single video GIF stream.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

Comment: Add `%matplotlib notebook` at the top after importing the libraries and use `ani.save('anim.gif', writer='imagemagick')`, it will give you `StopIteration` error, however the gif you want will be created in your current notebook folder.

Comment: Please note that I also added another `yield` statement in the beginning of the `change_colors` generator in order not to skip the first frame.